# URL encode form POST in ISO-8859-1 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) HTTP POST to a server that only accepts ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Unlike [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) in Java the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript only takes a string and no encoding.

It doesn't help to convert the string with [iconv](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/) because when encodeURIComponent is called on that the encoding is lost (or garbled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of URL encoders that supported character encoding but I didn't find any that honored the Unreserved Characters in RFC 3986 so [I made one myself](https://github.com/jonelf/encodeURI.js).

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

var encodeURI = function(str, encoding) {
  if (!encoding || encoding == 'utf8' || encoding == 'utf-8') {
    return encodeURIComponent(str);
  }

  var buf = iconv.encode(str, encoding);
  var encoded = [];

  for (var pair of buf.entries()) {
    var value = pair[1];
    // Test if value is unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.3
    if ((value >= 65 && value <= 90) || // A-Z 
      (value >= 97 && value <= 122) || // a-z
      (value >= 48 && value <= 57) || // 0-9
      value == 45 || value == 46 ||  // "-" / "."
      value == 95 || value == 126   // "_" / "~"      
    ) {
      encoded.push(String.fromCharCode(value));
    } else {
      var hex = value.toString(16).toUpperCase();
      encoded.push("%" + (hex.length === 1 ? '0' + hex : hex));
    }
  }
  return encoded.join("");
}

module.exports = encodeURI;
```